# Ошибка при установке библиотеки pycrypto

Tags: python

При попытке установки библиотеки Pycrypto выходит это:

```
    C:\Users\1>pip3 install pycrypto
    Collecting pycrypto
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de338892 
    19e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0_ejzyd\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-g0d_nukj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0_ejzyd\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-g0d_nukj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e0_ejzyd\pycrypto\
```

когда уже вставил код на сайт, увидел вверху кода ссылку. Нажал - скачался архив. [image: так выглядит архив]

Подскажите пожалуйста,  что с ним делать?

Comment: вот бы прочитать строчку `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: самое интересное, что я прочитал и даже установил. Проблему это не решило. Я не из тех кто сразу бежит за помощью, не пытаясь решить проблему самостоятельно. Я погуглил, попробовал - мне не удалось устранить проблему

Comment: Напишите ответ. Что именно не хватало? А чтоб не ругались в коментариях и не было ответов, которые не помогли - редактируйте вопрос и укажите что пытались сделать.

Answer (score 0):

[Похожая проблема уже рассматривалась](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

А по сути я решал её установкой пакета Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools